# Connecting Ubuntu Server 12.04 to public network (internet access)

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, dns

I have installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 on my computer. I want to setup my dedicated server for web server and also I already have my own domain for web hosting company.

I followed [these instructions](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p3) to install Ubuntu Server 12.04.

I just setup my server connect with a router and the router connect to Internet. That problem is I can't access my server from a public network. I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806683/ubuntu-server-12-04-cannot-connect-through-public-ip) way, and made forward port 80 in my router but it's still not working.

Output ifconfig

[eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:29:d8:ab:e4
          inet addr:192.168.0.117  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0]

Is there any way to connect my server to the internet?

Comment: you question is : Is there any way to connect to my server from the internet?  what's the output of `ifconfig` and `ping askubuntu.com`

Comment: I don't like that instructions, they do thing that are very novice unfriendly like enabling root, disabling apparmor, changing default shell... and that only on page 5.

Comment: As I know, that instruction one of the completed for build the your own server and I just follow that instruction for setting server in local network. Now I want to connect my server to internet, but I still could not find the way, Are there any way to do that?

Comment: How are you trying to access your server from the public side? You say you have a domain registered - do you have a DNS service set up to point your domain to your public IP address? Are you trying to access it with just your public IP address?

Comment: I try using putty for access from public network, but it's not working, I only allow to access my server in local and I also register my domain from web hosting company, that problem is I need public ip for using my domain.

Answer (score 1):

OP's own answer:

I found the anwers for my problem. So I just need to forward port 80 in my routers. Now I can access my server using internet network.